# Google map doesn't work with custom image marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to load a styled map with custom marker (custom image) in my site. I tried to write the script in an individual file, name script.js. I don't see the marker that i added in my script. But it works quite well when I add the script in the index.html file, just before the end tag of the body. Why is this happening, any idea?

Comment: What does your code look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Please tell us what about you tried ..

Answer (score -1):

Where do you include the reference to script.js?

If you are including it before the DOM has finished loading (or any other dependencies such as the google maps script) then it could be throwing a error.Have you checked the developer tools in your browser to see if there is a javascript error?

Have you tried include the reference to the script below all other scripts and just before the closing body tag? Or wrapping your script in an event listener to make sure the page has finished loading

Comment: I write the code in script.js and link it from the index.html. I linked it just before the end of the body tag with all other script link. Finally i write the code i index.php within in the <script></script> tag just before the end of the body tag instead writing the code in to the script.js file and its working very well. but my question is why it is not working when i put in to the another file like i did before.